# GC messages in Android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Please give me all the information about this three different lines and also OOM in Android and how to reduce it.

```
GC_EXPLICIT freed 1669K, 10% free 53715K/59335K, paused 2ms+4ms.
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 853K, 6% free 50216K/52935K, paused 18ms.
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 52515K/55239K, paused 2ms+3ms.
```

Comment: Do you work with bitmap? Post more log and code so we can help you out

Comment: These messages are normal information messages, they don't indicate that you're out of memory (though you're close, with only 5% free). What makes you think you're out of memory? Copy-paste the relevant messages. If there's a memory leak in your code, the messages won't tell you where, it's something you need to debug.

Comment: i got it, i will never recycle bitmap.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three lines are messages from the Garbage Collector (GC) [read this article on Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and the sizes (i.e 1669K, 53715K) are the sizes of memory freed by collecting and destroying objects that occupied that much RAM memory. Out Of Memory Error (OOM) is, in simple terms, the OS telling you that your application is consuming more memory than is allocated to it and that you should do something about it.

Now, in order to remove the OOM and for best practices please watch this excellent video about memory-management and best practices: [Google I/O 2012 - Doing More With Less](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM).